# SwiftData BAD_EXEC_ACCESS Model Container

Tags: swift, swift-data

I am working with Swift Data and this code was working and I made changes to other part of my code and now it just crashes on load which doesn't make any sense. It crashes in all simulators, preview and device

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ff7bb1838c8)

```swift
@MainActor
struct AnvilApp: App {
    let appContainer: ModelContainer = {
        do {
            let container = try ModelContainer(for: Exercise.self)
```

Exercise.swift

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class Exercise: Codable, Equatable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var force: Force?
    var level: Level
    var mechanic: Mechanic?
    var equipment: Equipment?
    var primaryMuscles: [Muscle]
    var secondaryMuscles: [Muscle]
    var instructions: [String]
    var category: Category
    var images: [String]
    
    static func == (lhs: Exercise, rhs: Exercise) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    init(){
        self.id = ""
        self.name = "N/A"
        self.level = Exercise.Level.beginner
        self.primaryMuscles = []
        self.secondaryMuscles = []
        self.instructions = []
        self.category = Exercise.Category.cardio
        self.images = []
    }

    // removed decode 
    // removed encode
}

extension Exercise {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey{
        case id, name, force, level, mechanic, equipment, primaryMuscles, secondaryMuscles, instructions, category, images
    }
    // enums have be removed
}
```

Comment: Swift data objects shouldn’t conform to Codable and you should not override Equatable for a number of reasons https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/maintaining-a-local-copy-of-server-data